# Oracle pagination sql using rownum and order by unique column , order by makes the sql very slow

Tags: oracle, pagination

I have a typical oracle pagination sql called from a web application like this.

SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT *             ( Very complex inner queries )
     FROM xyz table
     **ORDER BY unique_colunn DESC ==> killer**
)
WHERE  rownum >= 50 and rownum<100

The sql works fine(returns data) within 2 or 3 seconds , but once the order by clause is introduced, it kills the query , it takes 200+ secs , but i cannot remove the order by unique column , because that is the one that drives the pagination logic , since it is a inline view not able to add any tuning hints , any pointers?

Have tried rank() , row_num over etc instead of using order by in the where condition as suggested , nothing works.

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM (SELECT * ( Very complex inner queries ......`, then `SELECT * FROM TABLE( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY )`, then append a result of last query to the question.

Comment: What is XYZ table? Also the column on which the order by is being performed may not be indexed and hence will incur significant costs. See if you can add an index.